# How to handle the list view clicks for checkbox on navigation drawer

Tags: android, listview, navigation-drawer

I am working on an application in which i have navigation drawer opening from right to left. In this navigation drawer I need to handle the filters for an item.
I am inflating the ListView with checkbox and a text.The ListView is getting populated with checkbox and filter text but in my apps I am not able to handle the click event.

For ex. When a user select multiple checkbox then a click event should be fired and my app should be able to capture those checked boxes values. But when i am clicking on the checked no click event is getting handled.
But when i inflate the ListView with text and images i am able to handle the click events.

For reference my drawer layout is similar to the below diagram:
[image]

In My NavigationDrawerFragment class I am handling the click event as follows:

```
private class FilterDrawerItemClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

private void selectItem(int position) {
        currentSelectedPosition = position;
        if (drawerListView != null) {
            drawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
        if (drawerLayout != null ) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(fragmentContainerView);
        }
        // Fire the event off to the bus which.
        // bus.post(new NavItemSelectedEvent(position));
        bus.post(new FilterNavItemSelectedEvent(position));
    }
```

When i removed the checkbox from ListView it's able to handle but When i put the checkbox into the ListView I am not able to handle the click events.

I tried a lot of approach guys but getting no idea. I think this is one of common scenario for navigation drawer.

Thanx in advance !

Comment: Try this. http://bharathandroidified.blogspot.com/2011/12/sliding-drawer-with-simple-checkboxes.html

Answer (score 0):

According to your opinion if navigation drawer does not provide such support for checkbox you can use two custom imageview/Button represent as checked and unchecked checkbox. Another way, you may try and that is creating a custom animated activity with listview similar to navigation drawer.